# Is there any way to create one pointer type that can point to sets with different Comp template argument?

Tags: c++

I have two `set` objects declared as follows:

```
set<order, Comp1> s1(comp1);
set<order, Comp2> s2(comp2);
```

`comp1` and `comp2` are functors of type `Comp1` and `Comp2` respectively.

I am wondering if there is any way I can use a pointer of some type to point to either `s1` or `s2` depending on my needs?

`set<order>*` doesn't seem to work. I hoped to have a `map<int, set<order>*>` that tells me for a given index, which `set` (through the pointer) the index (and its associated info as stored in `order`) is in. Any way to make that map?

**UPDATE**: I am experimenting with function templates. 
The function prototype is:

```
template <typename IN, typename WAIT>
void process_incoming(multiset<order, IN> &incoming, multiset<order, WAIT> &waiting, int seq)
```

I have two `set`s: one with elements sorted ascending and the other descending. I have a function that handles when new elements are added to either one of the two sets, it needs to "eat out" the other `set`'s first few elements so that the elements in the two sets are non-overlapping (meaning that the ascending sorted set's first element is greater than the descending sorted set's first element). I can write two functions that handle the case when elements are added to one set, and another when elements are added to the other set. But most of the code is simply renaming the variables that denote the two sets. Things are fine until I need to be able also to erase some elements in the sets. I could have two maps and check these two maps to see if an element was in `s1` or in `s2`. But it would be nice to have one map that stores all these information.

Comment: There are unrelated types, `boost::variant` may help.

Comment: Couldn't using iterators to traverse s1 and s2 provide what you need for your solution?

Comment: Your problem seems to be caused by poor design. Perhaps we can help you better if you state the bigger problem that let you to this post.

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. Can you modify your question to explain _why_ you need this?

Comment: @zenith What is XY-problem? I will modify the question to state why I needed this.

Comment: @Walter Thanks for the kind offer. I updated the question with my original intent. Now that I think about it, I could avoided the customized `Comp` and just pick the end() elements for one set and pick the begin() elements for the other set. Then the pointer can point to either set.

Answer (score 1):

All template arguments are part of the type. To make a pointer that can point to both sets you need a "generic" pointer like `void *`, and then cast it to the proper type when you use it.

This casting makes the solution pretty much useless, as you then need to know the exact type of the pointer, if you cast it to the wrong type (i.e. cast it to `std::set<order, Comp2>*` when it's really pointing to `s1`) you have *undefined behavior*.

Depending on your design and use-cases you could use templates. This works well if you need to pass a pointer to either set to a generic function, or store it in a class.

In short: It's really not feasible unless in some cases when you can use templates.

Comment: I hoped to have a map<int, set<order>*> that tells me for a given index, which set the index is in. Any way to make that map?

Comment: @Rich The only solution to that is to use e.g. [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html) as suggested by Jarod42.

Answer (score 0):

This is where `union`s are useful.

```
union pSet
{
    set<order, Comp1>* comp1;
    set<order, Comp2>* comp2;
};

union pSet p.comp1 = &s1;
/* do work with pSet.comp1 */
p.comp2 = &s2;
/* ... */
```

You could probably come with better names though.

Comment: You still must keep track of which component of the `union` is actually active, i.e. you need a boolean flag for that. Otherwise, you run the risk of inadvertedly re-interpreting one type for the other, which gives you *undefined behaviour* as pointed out in [Joachim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33688730/1023390).

Comment: That's true, if the user of the union can't keep track of its state, the union must do it for her.